# How to accelerate replacing of matrix rows in a loop as quickly as possible?

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, replacement, linear-algebra

I am working with a very large sparse matrix (for example) given in what follows:

```
m = 50; n = 40; o = 30; size = m*n*o;
B = SparseArray[{
   {i_, i_} -> RandomReal[], {size, size - 1} -> 
    2., {i_, j_} /; Abs[i - j] == 5 -> 
    1., {i_, j_} /; Abs[3 i - j] == 2 -> 2.
   }, {size, size}, 0.]
```

This is a matrix of the size $60000\times 60000$ as a simple instance (in practice I have several of such matrices of higher sizes).

I wish to replace many rows of the matrix $B$ with special rows (here with zero rows) coming from boundary conditions. My list of rows' numbers are given by

```
index1 = Flatten[Table[{i, j, k}, {i, 1, m}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, o}], 2];
Table[ind = index1[[l]]; 
  If[ind[[1]] == 1 || ind[[2]] == n, var[l] = 0, var[l] = l], {l, 
   Length@index1}];
bounindex = Table[var[l], {l, Length@index1}];
```

And my zero row is produced by

```
vector1 = SparseArray@ConstantArray[0, size];
```

Now for doing the replacement only for the 0 numbers obtained in `bounindex`, I write the following replacing rule in a loop as simply as possible:

```
Table[Which[bounindex[[i]] == 0, B[[i]] = vector1], {i, 
    size}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

This works OK but it takes a tremendous time (in my real problem I have larger sizes)! 
So I am wondering if there is a speed-up technique to replace the special rows of the matrix $B$ with appropriate rows (that I want).

I would be thankful if some hints for accelerating such a replacement be given.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(updated)*

For later comparisons, I will store the value of `B`:

```
B0 = B;
```

**Original post**

Set all the rows to zero at once. First, use [`Pick`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick) to find the rows to be zeroed:

```
delete = Pick[Range[60000], bounindex, 0];
len = Length[delete]
```

> 2670

Here is the number of nonzero values before zeroing out rows:

```
Length @ B["NonzeroValues"]
```

> 219989

Next, use [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part) to set all of the rows to 0:

```
B[[delete]] = SparseArray[{}, {len, 60000}]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.00192, Null}

Here is the number of nonzero values after zeroing out rows:

```
Length @ B["NonzeroValues"]
```

> 208689

**Update**

The OP asked about replacements with a more complicated RHS (in his example the RHS could be constructed from an appropriate [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot) product of a sparse matrix with `B`). Here is an example with a random, but fairly sparse RHS:

```
sub = SparseArray @ RandomChoice[{.9999,.0001} -> {0, 1}, {2670, 60000}];
```

Using the same procedure as before:

```
B = B0;
Length @ B["NonzeroValues"]
B[[delete]] = sub; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> 219989
>
> {0.009667, Null}

Check:

```
Length @ sub["NonzeroValues"]
Length @ B["NonzeroValues"]

%-%%
```

> 16024
>
> 224713
>
> 208689

The timing above depends heavily on the sparsity of the substitute matrix.

One final note. @george2079 tried multiplying 2 sparse matrices as an alternative. A similar idea is to multiply a sparse array with a spare vector. This is also quite fast, but not as flexible (one can only zero out rows, not replace rows with some other desired row):

```
B = B0;
Length @ B["NonzeroValues"]

B = B SparseArray @ Clip @ bounindex; //AbsoluteTiming
Length @ B["NonzeroValues"]
```

> 219989
>
> {0.006694, Null}
>
> 208689

Comment: tricky use of sparsearray!

Comment: This is cool in my viewpoint. Now, I have an inquiry to see if it is possible to extend your response. Is there a way to generalize this way by a way at which several rows are replaced by a combination of some other rows? For instance, in the following piece of code: `Table[B[[i]] = (2 B[[i - 2 (n*o)]] + 
     4 B[[i - (n*o)]]), {i, size, 
    size - (n*o) + 1, -1}]; // AbsoluteTiming`

Comment: @Fazlollah I'm afk for a bit, but the rhs looks like a dot product of a matrix with 2s and 4s in the right place with B. If this matrix is Sparse, then the Dot product will be sparse, and then the same kind of Part assignment should work.

Comment: This response is great and fruitful for anyone solves high dimensional PDEs and wishes to impose the boundaries directly into the coefficient matrix. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps ReplacePart[] is the answer you are looking for:

```
index0 = Position[bounindex, 0];
Bnew=ReplacePart[B, index0 -> vector1];
```

It is as fast as the Table-version...

Comment: Does this do the replacement properly? Please re-check it.

Comment: ReplacePart command doesn't change B, Bnew(see my edit/answer is the 'replaced' matrix!

Answer (score 0):

Edit no this is not good. It seems the matrix multiplication expands the sparse arrays ( evidenced by  memory usage).

--

I dont know if this is good performance wise or not, but here is a simple idea:

construct a 1-base sparse array with a zero row and multiply:

```
B = B SparseArray[ {3, i_} -> 0, Dimensions[base] , 1]
```